# full-page div flowing past bottom and right of page

Tags: html, css, page-setup

I'm trying to set up this page so that some of the individual divs are scrollable while the page itself doesn't have overflow. I swear, I've done this a hundred times before, but I've always *just* managed to get the page functional, using a lot of work-arounds or just getting it right without knowing exactly why. This time, my issue is getting the bottom and right end of the page to remain within the viewport. I've tried a number of solutions that I found here and elsewhere, but nothing is working or I end up breaking the solution down the road.

My main question is **what is the best way to set up this page--and future pages--so that it remains within view and the border margins are 5px?** (The 5px is an arbitrary value, but I noticed that the margin at the top of the page is a little thinner than the rest.)

https://jsfiddle.net/puncushion/01w7qtxy/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Subtitle</p>
        </header>
        <main>
            <p>Some text for main content area.</p>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Thanks for the help y'all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.container` `width` and `height` from `100%` to like below. It calculates full height/width with margin. If you set `width:100%` and `margin:5px` then `width` is equal to `width` of window + additionally `10px` in `margin`.

```
 .container {
    height: calc(100% - 10px);
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    ..........
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you say that this would be a useful solution in general when setting up pages?

Comment: Yes, because `box-sizing: border-box;` doesn't include margin and there is probably no other way to calculate width.